# How to test functions inside react-native-action-sheet

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to create some tests using react-native-action-sheet

```
ActionSheet.showActionSheetWithOptions(
{
  options: ['Choose from library', 'Take a photo', 'Attach file', 'Cancel'],
  title: 'Upload your document',
  cancelButtonIndex: 3
},
idx => {
  if (idx === 0) {
    imageFromGallery()
  } else if (idx === 1) {
    imageFromCamera()
  } else if (idx === 2) {
    readFiles()
  }
}
```

)

I can test the following which works but how do I then test for each option, so that I can test `imageFromGallery` for example?

`expect(ActionSheet.showActionSheetWithOptions).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Now how to access each option?